# <option value not allowing first option to be selected

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I have a drop down menu and when trying to select the first option it's stating that nothing is selected.

```
 <form method="post" action="update.php">
 <select name="id" required=true value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
 <?php                         
   $row="SELECT pk_app_id, name FROM applications";
   while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
   echo "<option value =\"" . $row['pk_app_id'] . "\">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
   }
 ?>
 </select>
 <br />
 Status:
 Red    <input type="radio" value="red" name="status" />
 Yellow    <input type="radio" value="yellow" name="status" />
 Green    <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="green" name="status" />
 <br />
 Reason:
 <br />
 <select name="reason">
 <option value="" selected="selected" value="">Select Reason</option>
 <option value="ONLINE">Online</option>
 <option value="MAINTENANCE">Maintenance</option>
 <option value="ERROR">Error</option>
 <option value="OFFLINE">Offline</option>
 <option value="">No Reason</option>
 </select>
 <br />
 Description:
 <br />
 <textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="description" wrap="hard" maxlength="320" value="<?  
 php echo $row['description']; ?>" /></textarea>
 <br />
 <div align="right"> <input name="update" type="submit" value="Update"/>
 <?php date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); $today = date("m/d/Y g:i a"); ?>
 <input type="hidden" name="last_updated" value="<?php echo $today; ?>" />
 </form>
```

I'd either like where I can select the first option or even if I have to put a "Select" option at the top that's disabled. Either way if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please share the resulting HTML.

Comment: What is stating that nothing is selected?

Comment: The form on submittal since it's required=true if I leave the first option selected (IE not selecting anything at all because first one is populated from the SQL Query). I don't know what you mean by the resulting HTML it's in a form that submits to make changes to my database.

Comment: Whether this is populated by a query or not isn't really relevant. What's important is the generated markup, as well as how you're checking for a value. Also, is this an IE issue?

Comment: I [tried to reproduce the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/5h7wW/) but leaving the first option selected allowed it to submit.

Comment: I added the entire form hopefully maybe that'll show where I screwed up it worked before on a production site and now I'm redoing everything and it's broken on the dev. Sorry for any confusion in not posting the entire form sooner.

Comment: We need to see the resulting HTML. Your `<select name="id">` element. What is generated by the PHP?

Comment: It never makes it to the resulting HTML it fails on the form level. If I remove the required=true it works which I may just do because it defaults to an entry. I'm currently writing the post entries so don't really have anything to show.

Comment: I don't understand your usage of `$row`...it seems to have multiple definitions.  It would be much easier to debug if you were using different variables for different tasks.

Comment: So the page that you posted above never even renders?  How can you know that nothing is selected?  Please post the output of the page that you posted above (not update.php).  Using "view source" in the browser: what appears between `<form method="post" action="update.php">` and the first `<br />`?

Comment: When I hit <input name="update" type="submit" value="Update"/> it fails there. Stating "!Please select an item in the list". I removed the required=true and it works I'm just more curious as to why it wasn't working at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed required=true which may not be an option for everyone but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<select name="id" required=true value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
```

to

```
<select name="id" required=true>
```

Comment: Tried this and didn't work, still failed at the update button on the form. I removed required=true and just having the select name="id" works for me so I'm just going to do that. Just still am confused as to why it didn't work with it on there. I appreciate everyone's help and apologize for any confusion I may had caused.

Comment: Once again, since you never posted the html that the page you posted actually renders, it is very difficult to figure out why.  You shouldn't have to remove `required=true` attribute if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option with an empty value, your browser will not register it as selectable. Therefore if you're telling the browser that the field is required, the browser is doing its job by saying "Hey, you didn't input anything in this required field."